# difference between html tag and body tag

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a question, in this picture, I applied the background-color property to the html and body tags, but whats the difference in applying it to each one individually? Also, when I use the cursor tool to view the page's box model, I can see that both, the html and body tags end with the div element, but the background-color:green covers the entire viewport. Do you know why?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZHM.png)

Comment: Try this article: https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/  . And also googling is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a background on the html element, the body background will cover the page. If there is a background on the html element, the body background behaves just like any other element.